# Folder Permission

Tags: 16.04, permissions

I try to change folder permission. But it went wrong and mess up with all permission like this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hJaE.png

I tried

```
sudo chown -R root:root /var/www/html/
```

but nothing changed.

How can I revert back the permission or change owner ?

Note: I cannot add image direct to here due to insufficient reputation.

Comment: Ownership changed to root. But access set none. I want to revert back root access as read & write..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command you used gave ownership to the root user and group.  According to the image, it's done.  The only thing that probably needs to be changed is the access permission for the root user which now is **none**.  You can change it by typing:

`sudo chmod u+rw /var/www/html`

Comment: I tried this but unfortunately, I am unable to create a new file or directory. It throws permission denied error.